# How to click a certain group of elements in a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently trying to find a way to click a certain type of element on a web page. Eg. Click all the "Open" or "download" buttons on a webpage. I haven't been able to find a program online that does this and have decided to code the thing myself.

I am thinking I will make a chrome extension that once clicked will run through the page's elements and clicks the right ones.

Am I going about this the right way or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: you want this feature in a website coded by you or any website out there?

Comment: A pre-existing website I used to download multiple files daily. There is a download button for each file. So what I am trying to do is find a way to download all the files at once without clicking on every download button.

Answer (score 0):

```
;[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'), function (element) {
  var conditions = element.textContent === 'Open'
    || element.textContent === 'download'

  if (conditions) element.click()
})
```

Edit:  The code above uses `forEach` to iterate over every element ( denoted with `document.querySelectorAll('*')`.  While iterating over each element, it checks if the text content of the element currently being evaluated is either 'Open' or 'download'.  If one of those conditions are met then the element will be programmatically clicked.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. This code uses several specific naming conventions that the OP has not provided. Please provide some [context surrounding your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274), and see the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on how to write great answers :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to click all the buttons or links with a certain class you can do it like this:

`document.getElementsByClassName('foo').click();`

If you want to click a specific button or link that has an ID you can do it like this:

```
document.getElementsById('bar').click();
```